# WPF Combobox SelectionChanged record binding

Tags: wpf, combobox, listbox, selectionchanged

In my xaml, I have a ListBox of Customers on the left.  When a customer is selected, the right will display the customer info (name, address, phone, type, etc) to a bind textbox or combobox.

On the right, the Type is a combobox that has SelectionChanged event that populate something when value is changed.  The problem is whenever I select a different customer in the ListBox on the left, the Type SelectionChanged event also fire up and populate value.  How can I detect and prevent this from happening?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt sound like a problem that is complex however it has not been described well. Could you please give a better example?

Are you using the MVVM pattern? I would imagine that you could break down the view in to multiple Views and View models, for example a "CustomersListViewModel" and a "CustomerDetailsViewModel".

You could bind the ListBox to a collection of Customers and set the "SelectItem" to a property called "SelectedCustomer" (in the CustomersListViewModel), then when the selection is changed in the CustomersListBox, it would fire a method called "SelectedCustomerChanged" or something similar which would essentially new up a "CustomersDetailsViewModel" (passing the selected customer as a parameter) and this would display the new CustomerDetails.

It sounds to me like you have a single view which is swapping out a customer, which would of coarse fire the selectionchanged event on your combobox, causing your issue.
tion of Customers

Example:

**CustomersListViewModel**

- BindableCollection Customers (Bound to ListBox)
- Customer SelectedCustomer (Bound to ListBox SelectedItem)
- CustomerDetailViewModel CustomerDetailViewModel (Bound to a ContentControl)
- SelectedCustomerChanged (Fired on ListBox SelectionChanged Event)

**CustomerDetailViewModel** (Accepts a Customer object in constructor params)

- Customer CurrentCustomer (Bind
  controls to properties on this
  Customer object)

The "SelectedCustomerChanged" method would look something like this...

```
public void SelectedCustomerChanged()
{
   this.CustomerDetailViewModel = new CustomerDetailViewModel(this.SelectedCustomer)
   // Replace this with some activation of view code?
   this.ActivateViewModel(this.CustomerDetailViewModel)
}
```

That would be my approach?

Thanks, Hope this helps.

Ben

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm not using MVVM pattern.  It's a WPF application using EF for data.  I load the Listbox with Customers.  When a customer is selected, the windows DataContext is set to the SelectedItem.  I believe the ComboBox SelectionChanged event fired up because the Type changes each time a new customer is selected.  I need to know how to prevent the ComboBox SelectionChanged from executing when the change is not directly from the ComboBox drop-down-list change.